# Integer.parseInt(request.getParamerter("") thorws java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, exception, servlets

I'm trying to post a Data that is input by a user into a MySQL database.
I'm using a Servlet with the doPost method and a JSP with different multiple Inputs all the other Inputs which are string are fine the two int value won't parse though.

This is the Form with the Input this does have other inputs all type text or URL, savemovie is the Servlet that gets called.

```java
<section id="forms">
   <form name="movies" id="addmovie" action="savemovie" method="post">
            <label for="length">Länge</label>
            <input type="text" name="length" id="length">

            <label for="release">release</label>
            <input type="text" name="release" id="release">

            <input type="submit" value="Send">
   </form>
```

This is the Servlet

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {

     int length = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("length"));
     int release =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("release"));
```

These two values, later on, get added to a query which adds them and the other values to a Database
Both of these do not get parsed for some reason even though I'm using the exact same method on another part of Code(doget Method to fetch data based on an ID which was input by the user) and there it works just fine

Error Message is "java.lang.NumberFormatException: null" I did try with try/catch already did not parse either. I really do not know why these don't work but the other one does

Comment: Thank you khelwood for fixing the code section for this pleb.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing string values that can be converted to integer for the release and length request params?

Comment: They are numbers for sure, I was using 107 and 2016 as test parameters. If those are not string values that can be converted I'm gonna be quite baffled. I tried numpad and the 1-0 row.

Comment: It seems the form values are not reaching the method. I would suggest playing around with `getParameterMap()` to first see if the parameters are there and if not, why not.

Comment: The other 8 values inside the from do reach the method though. Gonna do that anyways can't hurt

Comment: Not really good with Java yet, could Someone explain how `getParameterMap()` works?

Comment: Did you try doing a debug?. Can you add a log/sout to see what exactly you get through `request.getParameter("length")` and see. Out of curiosity what's the language set in you computer?

Comment: Did try a Debug, can't use `request.getParameter("length")` as `length` is still a string at that point. Language is German dunno how that impacts it though x)

Comment: Try `String sLength = request.getParameter("length");` and then `int length = Integer.parseInt(sLength);` and debug (or put `System.out.println("LENGTH: " + sLength);` between those two lines). You will see, what really comes as parameter.

Comment: The `getParameterMap()` gives you back a `Map<String, String[]>` where keys are names of all the parameters, and values are string arrays with values of those parameters (because a parameter can have multiple values, e.g. for multiselect). You can iterate that map to see what's passed to the servlet. E.g. `request.getParameterMap().forEach( (n,v) -> System.out.println((n + ": " + Arrays.toString(v))));` - and watch the `catalina.out` file.

Comment: Thanks to Jozef, I narrowed it down to the length value that does apparently not get passed on. still, don't know why though.

Comment: Changed the Id of the Input to something that was not its name and now it works. Still works for every other value than "length". Thank you, everyone, for your help. Someone answer this so I don't have to answer all my questions for my self.

Answer (score 0):

Before parsing a string you should do null check and trim then parse. If NumberFormatException occurs handle it.

Whenever you get into trouble like this, put debug statements and analyse 
what actually causing exception. null or empty or whitespace or string? Then you can handle it easily.

```
Integer length= parseToNumber(request.getParameter("length"));
//check for not null and proceed

receivedParam = request.getParameter(request.getParameter("release"));
Integer release= parseToNumber(receivedParam);
//check for not null and proceed


// returns null if receivedParam = "", "some string", null or number with space
private Integer parseToNumber(String receivedParam)
{
    System.out.println("received param:"+receivedParam);
    if (receivedParam != null && !receivedParam.trim().isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(receivedParam.trim());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            System.out.println("received param is not a number");
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("received param is null or empty");
        return null;
    }
}
```